# Error in evaluating $\int \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^2 dx$.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am playing around with some integrals and I am in need of helping to spot an error in my manipulations.

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be an arbitrary $C^\infty$ (infinitely differentiable) and consider the task of integrating $\int ( \frac{df}{dx} )^2 dx$.

**Note:** I use the abbreviations WLOG (without loss of generality) and COI (constant of integration) below.

$$\begin{align}
\int dx\ \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^2 & = \int df\ \frac{df}{dx} \\
&= \int df \int dx\ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} \\
&= \int dx \int df\ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} & \text{let $u=\frac{df}{dx}$, so $du = \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}\ \frac{dx}{df}\ df$} \\
&= \int dx\ \int du\ u \\
&= \int dx\ \left[ \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{C}{2} \right] & \text{WLOG let $\frac{C}{2} \in \mathbb R$ be COI} \\
&= \int dx\ \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^2 + \frac{C}{2} \right] \\
&= \frac{Cx}{2} + \frac K2 +\frac{1}{2} \int dx\ \left( \frac{df}{dx} \right)^2 & \text{WLOG let $\frac{K}{2} \in \mathbb R$ be COI} \\
&= Cx + K
\end{align}$$

It is obviously nonsense to state that $\int ( \frac{df}{dx} )^2 dx$ must be a linear function in $x$ for all functions $f$, so where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Hard to say, since everything here is informal in the first place, and pure symbolism. Maybe if you replaced indefinite integrals with definite ones, it'd make more sense. In my opinion, it's the second line when it all crumbles. When you introduce an indefinite integral under another indefinite integral.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Somehow it never occurred to me that multiple indefinite integrals weren't valid. I can try to see what will happen if I try to rephrase this proof in terms of definite integrals instead of indefinite ones.

Comment: I'm confused at $∫ (f')^2 dx = ∫ f' df$, is this substitution?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I substituted $df = f' dx$ in that line.

Comment: @TrevorKafka having $f'$ as a function of the variable $f$, while also saying that it is valid to use $f$ as a change of variables is a restriction. It's possible that under these restrictions the integral can only have the simple formula you found

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's an interesting thought. I've never heard of any restrictions on what you can and can't use in substitution, though. I can see $f$ not being invertable posing a problem here, but even if it were, it wouldn't be enough to reduce the solution to just something linear. Definitely could be a part of the problem, but I don't think it can be the entire problem.

Comment: @TrevorKafka I was more worried about the first point, suppose say that $f'=f$. Then immediately it's an exponential. What functions are of the form $f'=u(f)$, with $u$ integrable? Edit- actually this can't be it because the indefinite integral of $\exp(2x)$ is not linear in $x$

Comment: @TrevorKafka Don't see how you justify the $\,3^{rd}\,$ $\,=\,$ sign. Try it with a simple case like $\,f(x)=e^{2x}\,$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor If $f(x) = e^x$, then on one hand we'd have $\int dx\ (\frac{df}{dx})^2 = \int dx\ e^{2x} = e^{2x}/2 + C$ and on the other hand we'd have $\int df\ \frac{df}{dx} = \int d(e^x) e^x = e^{2x}/2 + C$, so that seems to be ok...

Comment: @TrevorKafka Sorry for being unclear, I was comparing the very first line with the final line, $Cx + K$ in the case of an exponential

Comment: @CalvinKhor I definitely agree that the first line doesn't equal the last line. Just unsure where the problem is. Currently working out dxiv's suggestion on paper.

Comment: @dxiv I think you've spotted it. I naïvely treated it as a multi integral where you can just swap the order of integration without issue. I think this only works when the differentials are independent of each other. $df$ and $dx$ are dependent. It's clearer to see that $\int df \int dx \ne \int dx \int df$ if one notes that clearly $\int dx\ f' \int dx \ne \int dx\ \int dx\ f'$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is increasing on $[0,1]$, is in $C^2[0,1]$, and $f'(x) = u(f(x))$ for some $u\in C^1[f(0),f(1)]$. Then for $y\in [0,1]$,
\begin{align} \int_0^y (f'(x))^2 dx 
&= \int_0^yu(f(x))f'(x)dx = \int_{f(0)}^{f(y)}u(\tilde f)d\tilde f \\&= \int_{f(0)}^{f(y)} u(f(0)) + \int_{f(0)}^\tilde f u'(z) dz d\tilde f\end{align}
So we see that we need $u(f(0)) = 0$. Note $$f''(x) = u'(f(x)) f'(x)$$ which means that
$$ u'(z) = \frac{f''(f^{-1}(z))}{f'(f^{-1}(z))} $$
Attempting to proceed with $u(f(0)) = 0$, we can invert the change of variables $z = f(\tilde x)$
$$\int_0^y (f')^2 dx = \int_{f(0)}^{f(y)}\int_0^{f^{-1}(\tilde f)}f''(\tilde x) d\tilde x d\tilde f$$
which is similar to what you have. the exchange of integrals now gives
$$\int_{f(0)}^{f(y)}\int_0^{f^{-1}(\tilde f)}f''(\tilde x) d\tilde x d\tilde f = \int_{0}^{y} f''(\tilde x) \int_{f(\tilde x)}^{f(y)}  d\tilde f d\tilde x$$
where $f''$ is written as a function of $\tilde x$, not of $\tilde f$, so it doesn't seem like it can be meaningfully involved in another change of variables for the $d\tilde f$ integral.

I think the rest of the computation can't be saved, but this identity is not without merit. It implies for instance an inequality betweeen norms of derivatives of functions in this class,

\begin{align} \|f'\|_{L^2}^2 & \le |f'(0)||f(1) - f(0)| + \int_0^1 |f''(x)| |f(1) - f(x)| dx \\ &\le 2\|f'\|_{L^\infty}\|f\|_{L^\infty}+ 2\|f''\|_{L^1} \|f\|_{L^\infty}\end{align}

Comment: Do you mind explaining the third equality? I don't quite follow (sorry!).

Comment: @TrevorKafka Its FTC, note that $f(x) = \int_0^x f' $ only if $f(0) = 0$. cf. $\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a)$

Comment: @TrevorKafka the part I previously typed actually doesn't seem wrong. I've moved on to dxiv's remark...